# An Unknown Error occurred in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, xcode5

I'm trying to test out my app on my ipad and when I decide to run it on my ipad, Xcode says that it's successfully built. On the top, it says that it's runnning the app, but nothing happens for 2-3 minutes. Finally, I get two screens popping up saying "An unknown error occurred." I have tried running other apps through Xcode on my ipad and they work fine. I also decided to exit Xcode and restart everything, but the problem still exists. Does anyone know what the problem is?

Not sure if this will be useful but
Xcode Version: 5.1.1
Ipad Version: 7.0.4
Mac OS X 10.9

Comment: Try deleting the app off your iPad.

Comment: Does running in the simulator work? Have you placed breakpoints in you app delegate to step through the launch process?

Comment: It works in the simulator.

Comment: Nevermind. Figured it out. Turns out my ipad lacked enough storage space.

Answer (score 15):

I found one approach:

Before this approach make sure that you have all certificates and other documentation updated.

I have faced same issue, now I have a way to fix this. I am using iPhone 5 with OS version 9.1

First, delete the app from your device and then restart the xcode by force quit and then again open it. Now clean your project and run the project in your device. Now it will be run without any issue.

Comment: Hi Gourav Joshi, regarding [this review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/24621304), you need to be more careful and test the changes in a Playground before approving them: you should have rejected the suggested edit.

Answer (score 8):

Close your simulator or unplug and plug back in your device, and re-select the device target.

Answer (score 1):

In my case . I cleaned the product and rebuild it and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Sometime is you forget to unlock your device.